# SQL Server Computed Columns - split on line break

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a column with name and address data in a single column:

```
Jo Bloggs
Address Line 1
Address Line 2
PostCode
```

Is it possible to then create two computed columns based on this, and if so how? e.g.

RecipientName

```
Jo Bloggs
```

Address

```
Address Line 1
Address Line 2
PostCode
```

I'm using SQL Server 2005

Comment: Depends on how you decide to split the columns? Based on what criteria do you decide Name and Address values?

Comment: It is existing data, could be from another database or from an imported CSV. First line is assumed to be the name. The rest of the lines are the address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this;

```
CREATE TABLE ...
(
 ...
 WholeAddress  VARCHAR(256),
 RecipientName AS dbo.fnGetAddressPart(1, WholeAddress),
 Address       AS dbo.fnGetAddressPart(2, WholeAddress)
)
```

Where the UDF is along the lines of;

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnGetAddressPart (@PARTID TINYINT, @DATA VARCHAR(256)) RETURNS VARCHAR(256) AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @POS INT SET @POS = CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), @DATA, 1)
    IF (@POS = 0 OR LEN(@DATA) <= 2) --no new lines or just \r\n
        RETURN CASE @PARTID
            WHEN 1 THEN @DATA --return name only
            ELSE '' --no address part
        END

    RETURN CASE @PARTID
        WHEN 1 THEN LEFT(@DATA, @POS - 2)
        ELSE RIGHT(@DATA, LEN(@DATA) - @POS - 1)
    END
END
```

However it would be better to break out the address elements into individual fields.